# Extjs Panel: how to turn 'frame' property to 'true' dynamically?

Tags: extjs, panel

I use this code to make a panel->frame value = true at run time:

Ext.apply(mypanel, {frame: 'true'});

but it doesn't work !!

and when I use:
Ext.apply(mypanel, {collapsible: 'true'});
it is working fine!!

Do I miss something here, how can I turn a panel->frame to true at run time?

Comment: you need to clarify the timing of your apply method. runtime could mean before or after rendering, and before or after instantiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ext.apply(mypanel, {frame: 'true'});
mypanel.setUI(mypanel.ui + '-framed');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of ExtJS you are using but in ExtJS 4.0.7 (and also in 4.1.3, there is different implementation but with same meaning) if your borwser supports CSS3 border radius (check value of `Ext.supports.CSS3BorderRadius`) then frame is not created regardless value of frame property of instance.

See source code of [Ext.AbstractComponent.initFrame](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/AbstractComponent.html) (ExtJS 4.0.7)
or [Ext.AbstractComponent.addUIClsToElement](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/AbstractComponent.html) (ExtJS 4.1.3)

Comment: Well, IE doesn't support border radius. I have one more question. Why do you set value of frame as string (`'true'`)? It is defined boolean so you have to se `true` (without apostrophe). And if you use ext-all-dev.js you probably get an error during frame initialization because you have to have defined CSS styles for framed components. See [Ext.util.Renderable.getFrameInfo] (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Renderable.html#Ext-util-Renderable-method-getFrameInfo).